# android copy /dev/log/* to SD card failer

Tags: android, system, android-sdcard

GUYS

I'm **new** to android and this is my first post in StackOverflow.English as my second language,I'm not that good at it.I just looked for some answers here before,Now I think it's time for me to get involved in it.

There have been a problem occured when I try to copy the system log which located in /dev/log/* to my SD card.After some search on the answers here,I came across [Copy file (image) from CacheDir to SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029880/copy-file-image-from-cachedir-to-sd-card).So I had my code below:

```
private final String srcLocation = "/dev/log/radio";
private final String desLocation = "/mnt/sdcard/radio";

FileInputStream src;
FileOutputStream dst;
FileChannel mFCsrc;
FileChannel mFCdst;

public boolean copyFile(String sourceLocation, String destLocation) throws IOException {
          try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                if(sd.canWrite()){
                    File source=new File(sourceLocation);
                    File dest=new File(destLocation);
                    if(!dest.exists()){
                        dest.createNewFile();
                    }
                    if(source.exists()){
                        src = new FileInputStream(source);
                        dst = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                        mFCsrc = src.getChannel();
                        mFCdst = dst.getChannel();
                        mFCsrc.transferTo(0, mFCsrc.size(), mFCdst);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (mFCsrc != null) {
                    mFCsrc.close();
                }
                if (mFCdst != null) {
                    mFCdst.close();
                }
            }
    }
```

I do have the file in my SD card which I can see it from my DDMS window,but it's size is 0.So,anyone gets a clue? Thanks in advance.(**I try to give you a picture of my DDMS window,but since my reputation is not enough,I cann't use a picture.I'm sorry about that!!**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should debug. Step trough your code with the debugger and check what is happening.

Random thing that might be happening, but we have no way of knowing for sure: If "source" doesn't exist, you will create `dest`, but because `source.exists()` will return false,you don't do anything after that. You'll end up with the current behaviour, a newly created file without contents.